# Unable to resolve images when publishing to remote server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have just published a website to a remote server but I am unable to view the images which I refference as follows:

```
<a href="ProductDetails.aspx?productID=<%#:Item.ProductID%>">
        <img src="/Catalog/Images/Thumbs/<%#:Item.ProductImageName%>"
                width="100" height="75" style="border: solid" /></a>
```

While this seems to work on a local server, it does not on the remote one even if permissions are set. The strange thing is that in the remote server, the pictures are located in exactly the same place as in the local server.

Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the file permissions are high enough on the directory that the files are stored in?

Comment: Permissions are not the problem in this case, they are set

Answer (score 0):

Changing the path to this :

```
../Catalog/Images/Thumbs/
```

Fixed he problem, the code should be:

```
<a href="ProductDetails.aspx?productID=<%#:Item.ProductID%>">
                                <img src="../Catalog/Images/Thumbs/<%#:Item.ProductImagePath%>"
                                    width="150" height="100" style="border: solid" /></a>
```